# Image Processing: Image has grid lines after applying filter

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm very new to working with image processing at a low level and have just had a go at implementing a gaussian kernel with both GPU and CPU - however both yield the same output, an image which is severely skewed by a grid:

[image: Showing Blur kernel on CPU]

I'm aware I could use OpenCV's pre-built functions to handle the filters, but I wanted to learn the methodology behind it, so I built my own.

Convolution kernel:

```
// Convolution kernel - this manipulates the given channel and writes out a new blurred channel.
void convoluteChannel_cpu(
                        const unsigned char* const channel,         // Input channel
                        unsigned char* const channelBlurred,        // Output channel
                        const size_t numRows, const size_t numCols, // Channel width/height (rows, cols)
                        const float *filter,                        // The weight of sigma, to convulge
                        const int filterWidth                       // This is normally a sample of 9
                     )
{
    // Loop through the images given R, G or B channel
    for(int rows = 0; rows < (int)numRows; rows++)
    {
        for(int cols = 0; cols < (int)numCols; cols++)
        {
            // Declare new pixel colour value
            float newColor = 0.f;

            // Loop for every row along the stencil size (3x3 matrix)
            for(int filter_x = -filterWidth/2; filter_x <= filterWidth/2; filter_x++)
            {
                // Loop for every col along the stencil size (3x3 matrix)
                for(int filter_y = -filterWidth/2; filter_y <= filterWidth/2; filter_y++)
                {
                    // Clamp to the boundary of the image to ensure we don't access a null index.
                    int image_x = __min(__max(rows + filter_x, 0), static_cast<int>(numRows -1));
                    int image_y = __min(__max(cols + filter_y, 0), static_cast<int>(numCols -1));

                    // Assign the new pixel value to the current pixel, numCols and numRows are both 3, so we only 
                    // need to use one to find the current pixel index (similar to how we find the thread in a block)
                    float pixel = static_cast<float>(channel[image_x * numCols + image_y]);

                    // Sigma is the new weight to apply to the image, we perform the equation to get a radnom weighting,
                    // if we don't do this the image will become choppy.
                    float sigma = filter[(filter_x + filterWidth / 2) * filterWidth + filter_y + filterWidth/2];
                    //float sigma = 1 / 81.f;

                    // Set the new pixel value
                    newColor += pixel * sigma;
                }
            }

            // Set the value of the next pixel at the current image index with the newly declared color
            channelBlurred[rows * numCols + cols] = newColor;
        }
    }
}
```

I call this 3 times from another method which splits the image into respective R, G, B channels, but I don't believe this would cause the image to be so severely mutated.

Has anybody encountered a problem similar to this before, and if so how did you solve it?

**EDIT** Channel Splitting Func:

```
void gaussian_cpu(
                    const uchar4* const rgbaImage,       // Our input image from the camera
                    uchar4* const outputImage,           // The image we are writing back for display
                    size_t numRows, size_t numCols,      // Width and Height of the input image (rows/cols)
                    const float* const filter,           // The value of sigma
                    const int filterWidth                // The size of the stencil (3x3) 9
                 )
{
    // Build an array to hold each channel for the given image
    unsigned char *r_c = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols];
    unsigned char *g_c = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols];
    unsigned char *b_c = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols];

    // Build arrays for each of the output (blurred) channels
    unsigned char *r_bc = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols]; 
    unsigned char *g_bc = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols]; 
    unsigned char *b_bc = new unsigned char[numRows * numCols]; 

    // Separate the image into R,G,B channels
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numRows * numCols; i++) 
    {
        uchar4 rgba = rgbaImage[i];
        r_c[i] = rgba.x;
        g_c[i] = rgba.y;
        b_c[i] = rgba.z;
    }

    // Convolute each of the channels using our array
    convoluteChannel_cpu(r_c, r_bc, numRows, numCols, filter, filterWidth);
    convoluteChannel_cpu(g_c, g_bc, numRows, numCols, filter, filterWidth);
    convoluteChannel_cpu(b_c, b_bc, numRows, numCols, filter, filterWidth);

    // Recombine the channels to build the output image - 255 for alpha as we want 0 transparency
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numRows * numCols; i++) 
    {
        uchar4 rgba = make_uchar4(r_bc[i], g_bc[i], b_bc[i], 255);
        outputImage[i] = rgba;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Calling the kernel

```
while(gpu_frames > 0)
{
    //cout << gpu_frames << "\n";
    camera >> frameIn;

    // Allocate I/O Pointers
    beginStream(&h_inputFrame, &h_outputFrame, &d_inputFrame, &d_outputFrame, &d_redBlurred, &d_greenBlurred, &d_blueBlurred, &_h_filter, &filterWidth, frameIn);

    // Show the source image
    imshow("Source", frameIn);

    g_timer.Start();
    // Allocate mem to GPU
    allocateMemoryAndCopyToGPU(numRows(), numCols(), _h_filter, filterWidth);

    // Apply the gaussian kernel filter and then free any memory ready for the next iteration
    gaussian_gpu(h_inputFrame, d_inputFrame, d_outputFrame, numRows(), numCols(), d_redBlurred, d_greenBlurred, d_blueBlurred, filterWidth);

    // Output the blurred image
    cudaMemcpy(h_outputFrame, d_frameOut, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    g_timer.Stop();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gpuTime += g_timer.Elapsed();
    cout << "Time for this kernel " << g_timer.Elapsed() << "\n";

    Mat outputFrame(Size(numCols(), numRows()), CV_8UC1, h_outputFrame, Mat::AUTO_STEP);

    clean_mem();

    imshow("Dest", outputFrame);

    // 1ms delay to prevent system from being interrupted whilst drawing the new frame
    waitKey(1);
    gpu_frames--;
}
```

And then within the beginStream() method, images are converted to uchar4:

```
 // Allocate host variables, casting the frameIn and frameOut vars to uchar4 elements, these will
 // later be processed by the kernel
*h_inputFrame = (uchar4 *)frameIn.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
*h_outputFrame = (uchar4 *)frameOut.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
```

Comment: I don't think you are taking into consideration that the input image is RGB and has 3-channels. If your algorithm outputs a 1-channel image, it's best to convert the input image to a single channel before executing the algorithm.

Comment: This kind of glitch seems to be related to the number of input/output channels.

Comment: Hmmm, is there anything obvious in my solution which could be skewing the output?

Comment: Change your algorithm to perform a grayscale conversion, and you will see.

Comment: @Alex... Can you show how you are calling the `gaussian_cpu` function? As far as I know, OpenCV's `VideoCapture` object returns a **3** channel image, not **4**.

Comment: That sounds promising @sgarizvi, updated code to reflect the call

Comment: your filterWidth should be 3, not 9. also, you have to spare a border to avoid overflow: `for(int rows=filterWidth/2; rows < (int)numRows-filterWidth/2; rows++)` (same for cols)

Comment: @berak I tried a width of 3 as well - had the same results.

Comment: btw, `for(int filter_x = -filterWidth/2; filter_x <= filterWidth; filter_x++)` (use the full width, not the left half only)

Comment: Thanks Berak I shall try that :)

Comment: @berak the filtering is done in the full length itself. (-x to x), where x is width/2.

Comment: ^^ true, misread it.

Comment: Yes that's correct, allows me to sample the negative indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many doubts in the problem.
At the start of the code, its mentioned that the filter width is 9, thus making it a 9x9 kernel. But in some other comments its said to be 3. So I am guessing that you are actually using a 9x9 kernel and the filter do have the 81 weights in them.

But the above output can never be due to the above mentioned confusion.

uchar4 is of 4-byte size. Thus in gaussian_cpu while splitting the data by running the loop over rgbaImage[i] on an image that doesnot contain alpha value (it could be inferred from the above mentioned loop that alpha is not present) what actually gets done is that your are copying R1,G2,B3,R5,G6,B7 and so on to the red-channel. Better you initially try the code on a grayscale image and make sure you are using uchar instead of uchar4.

The output image seems exactly 1/3rd the width of the original image, which makes the above assumption to be true.

**EDIT 1:**

Is the input rgbaImage to guassian_cpu function RGBA or RGB? videoCapture must be giving a 3 channel output. The initialization of `*h_inputFrame` (to uchar4) itself is wrong as its pointing to 3 channel data. 
Similarly the output data is four channel data, but `Mat outputFrame` is declared as a single channel which points to this four channel data. Try Mat outputFrame as `8UC3 type` and see the result.

Also, how is the code working, the guassian_cpu() function has 7 input parameters in the definition, but when you call the function 8 parameters are used. Hope this is just a typo.

Comment: Sorry anoop, to clear confusion it is a 3x3 filter,  only reason I put 9 on the comment was to remind me of the total size after multiplication

Comment: What you've said makes sense,  but when I take the image in the gaussiancpu method and split the channels, I put 255 into the alpha.   Maybe I should drop this and just use uchar ?

Comment: As for the kernel being called wrong, I've just realised I posted the GPU kernel call instead of the CPU - I can assure you the params do match up :P - The beginStream() function convert the initial BGR image captured from the camera into a RGBA, then it casts it to a uchar4, writes it back to the h_output pointer in preparation for the kernel.

Comment: If thats true, then "Mat outputFrame(Size(numCols(), numRows()), CV_8UC1, ...)" is to be modified to CV_8UC4 and the code must work

Comment: I shall give that a shot when I am home Anoop - thanks for your input, theres a lot I have to learn before I'm going to get good at this :P

Comment: I'm guessing 8UC4 creates an image in RGBA format - maybe what I've done so far conflicts and skews the input data?

Comment: Yes, right now you are assigning the values of R1 G1 B1 A1 R2 G2 B2 A2 to a gray image thus making these values to be read as Gr1 Gr2 Gr3 Gr4 Gr5 Gr6 Gr7 Gr8 etc

Comment: That makes complete sense, I'll try and amend that

Comment: @Alex..Try converting your input image to an actual 4 channel image using `cv::cvtColor(frameIn,frameIn,cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA)` just after `camera>>frameIn`. Your `gaussian_cpu` function is working fine, just provide it properly allocated input and output images.

Comment: @sgarizvi i expect 'gaussian_cpu' to work even now. But as long as the output is being pointed to a gray matrix, the display wont get corrected. Alex, did it work?

Comment: Problem is fixed now after following your suggestions thanks again